# Veracrypt: command line only

Tags: command-line, mount, truecrypt, veracrypt

I want to use veracrypt without an init server.
Is this possible?

```
veracrypt --mount container /mnt/point
```

gives me:

> No protocol specified Unable to init server: Could not connect:
>   Connection refused 00:15:54: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is
>   DISPLAY set properly?

Answer (score -1):

`tcplay with --veracrypt-mode` seems to solve the issue.